# Data structure that inserts in O(log2n), yet searches in O(1)

Tags: structure, hashtable, binary-search-tree

Currently working on an assignment that requries a  data structure to insert in O(log2n), yet be able to search for an element in O(1). I was thinking a BST because of the log2n insert, but will be unable to search in O(1). A hash table can insert at worst O(n), with a search of O(1), but unfortunately this doesn't fit the O(log2n) insert requirements.

Anybody have any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert element into a binary tree, and pointer to that element - into hashtable.

Or, you can just insert element into hashtable with O(1), and search with O(1), and for comply requirement "Insert O(lb N)" - just run LogBin(N) empty loops.

Regarding "worst case/average case": both hashtable and binary tree (non balanced like rb, just primitive) has O(N) in worst case. I think, your assignment is about "average case", this is usual. And hashtable can provide O(1). To preserve attack with selected dataset, use the "[universal hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing)".